# Exporting Kusto table to SQL Server GENERATED ALWAYS column

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm setting up a data pipeline to export from a Kusto table to a SQL Server table. The only problem is the target table has two `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns. Looking for some help implementing the solution using Kusto.

This is the export statement:

```
.export async to sql ['CompletionImport']
h@"connection_string_here"
with (createifnotexists="true", primarykey="CompletionSearchId")
<|set notruncation;
apiV2CompletionSearchFinal
| where hash(SourceRecordId, 1) == 0
```

Which gives the error:

```
Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'server.dbo.CompletionImport'. 
Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column.
```

So I'm a little unsure how to implement this solution in Kusto. Would I just add a `project` pipe excluding the `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns? Maybe ideally how could I insert a `DEFAULT` value into `GENERATED ALWAYS` SQL Server columns using a Kusto query?

---

**Edit:** Trying to use `materialize` to create a temporary table in the cache and export this cached table. However I can't find any documentation on this and the operation is failing:

```
let dboV2CompletionSearch = apiV2CompletionSearchFinal 
| project every, variable, besides, generated, always, ones;
 let cachedCS = materialize(dboV2CompletionSearch);

.export async to sql ['CompletionImport']
h@"connect_string"
with (createifnotexists="true", primarykey="CompletionSearchId")
<|set notruncation;
cachedCS
| where hash(SourceRecordId, 1) == 0
```

with the following error message:

```
Semantic error: 'set notruncation;
cachedCS
| where hash(SourceRecordId, 1) == 0' 
has the following semantic error: SEM0100: 
'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'cachedCS'.
```

Comment: Hi Steve - Going through Stack Overflow in search of issues, where it appears there is no response from the community and no resolution here?! Did you get this figured out? I am in the process of attempting to reproduce your issue but before I spend too much time, I wanted to see where you were at with this? Azure Data Explorer has a Continuous Export feature: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export Also, export from an `External` table: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-table-commands

Comment: oh yeah thanks for checking this - i got it figured out, it was a problem with the syntax relating to the variable types in the table i believe